# Can't close browser in Remote Driver after timeout

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i have following selenium Remote Driver code and when not found element, thrown error but browser doesn't closed. what could be reason and how can solve it?

```
driver = webdriver.Remote("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub", webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX.copy())
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("http://www.google.com")
print driver.title

driver.find_element(By.ID, "unknownElement")

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a try-except block - this way you can catch the exception and still continue in the program flow:

```
try:
  driver.find_element(By.ID, "unknownElement")
except:
  // do something like logging?

driver.quit()
```

Or just use another approach with find_elements - this way you just do nothing if no element is found:

```
elements = driver.find_elements(By.ID, "unknownElement")

if elements:
  # do something with your element via elements[0]
else:
  # do whatever you want when no element is found

driver.quit()
```